# Recoil library - recoil's value disappears after routers change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following recoil atom:

```js
export const BasketA = atom({
    key: 'basket',
    default: [] as any
})
```

Components on route `/test` which updates this:

```js
    const [basket, setBasket] = useRecoilState(BasketA);

    const handleAddBookToBasket = () => {
        setBasket((basket: any) => [...basket, book]);
    }
```

Now if we go to the basket route `/basket` and do:

```js
    const basket = useRecoilValue(BasketA)
```

When i console.log this basket, the basket is empty. I know that adding items to basket works, cuz in the first component, console logs displayed correct with filled data

So, my question is: Why the basket is empty after redirect to another route

Comment: I tried the logic of your code and
running basically without problems.
So I have two questions for you.
1. Where is your RecoilRoot?
2. How did you jump from /test to /basket

Comment: 1. RecoilRoot is in my main index.tsx
2. useNavigate()

Comment: I use useNavigate for jumping and it works fine, what is your error message? Or what was the result you were expecting, and what was the result you got?

Comment: const handleAddBookToBasket = () => {
        setBasket((basket: any) => [...basket, book]);
    }   Where did book get this data from?

Comment: I am expecting to get filled array of object, but when I do console.log I get empty array

Comment: The data was successfully added in recoil, but got empty in another page. The scenario of my situation is that when I jumped, I did not jump through the normal route, but manipulated the browser's address bar to jump, which means that the jump was not a single page jump, so the data was lost, and you seem to jump through the react-router to jump, so it's hard for me to tell where your problem is in that step.

Comment: It's hard for me to help you locate the problem without a specific and complete project code, so I'll teach you a way to locate the problem, and that is to subtract, you can go to sites like codesandbox.io, or define a new clean project locally, or create two new clean jsx files in your existing project, and then write the simplest atom example in it If it works, then the recoil is fine and you have a wrong part of the code, and you can lighten your code a little until you find that part